# How to add a PHP script to wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have a code that fetch data from an API and add the data as posts in Wordpress. It's suppose to run hourly.

I don't understand where i place this script in wordpress?

This is the script, it's a php class with a hourly trigger.

```
class MND_News_Importer
{
    private function _schedule_import()
        {
            // If the schedule isn't set
            if ( !wp_next_scheduled( self::CRON_NAME ) )
            {
                // Use the built in function wp_schedule event to run the function every hour
                wp_schedule_event( time(), 'hourly', self::CRON_NAME );
            }
        }
}
```

Full code can be found here: http://webbgaraget.se/2014/05/28/importera-nyheter-fran-mynewsdesk-till-wordpress-del-1/

Where am i suppose to place this code?

Comment: You can make it a template & assign that template to any page of wordpress & put that page URL in your cron job command.

Comment: create a new file inside a plugin folder `mynewsdesk-importer.php` and paste the full code. It will create a plugin for wordpress. Now go to admin and activate the plugin and you are done.

Comment: So if i run this page once with the plugin activated, will the wp_schedule_event( time(), 'hourly', self::CRON_NAME ); keep running every hour forward?

Answer (score 1):

You can add this class into function.php file in WordPress.

function.php location wp-content/themes/(activeTheme)/function.php

Comment: Can i just add the whole class? or do i need to init it